# vue.js replace jpg by animated gif on mouseover

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list of video poster images/jpgs rendered with vue.js. On mouse over these images should be replaced by a gif animation. On mouseout I expect to see the image/jpg again. So fare I was able to track the mouseover/out events but replacing the src-Attribute doesn't work as expected:

```
<div v-for="video in videos">
    <img 
      v-on:mouseover="mouseOver(video.id)" 
      v-on:mouseout="mouseOut(video.id)" 
      v-bind:src="mouse[video.id] === 1 ? 'images.gif' : 'images.gif'"
    />    
</div>


var app4 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-videomanager',
  router,
  data: {
    mouse: {} // the id is alphanumeric
  },
  computed: {
    videos() {
      return store.state.videos; // not included in the example
    }
  },
  methods: {
    mouseOver: function(id) {
      this.mouse[id] = 1;
    },
    mouseOut: function(id) {
      this.mouse[id] = 0;
    }
  }
});
```

Would it make sense to replace the src-attribute inside the mouseOver and mouseOut functions instead of puting too much logic into the component template? How can I manipulate this part of the DOM in vue.js?

Comment: The ids are not present in `mouse` when you declare it, so Vue does not make them reactive when you set them. See [Vue.set](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

Comment: The ids were present. This part of my solution was working. maxpaj provided an elegant solution for me.

Comment: If you declared it as you said: `mouse: {} `, there were no `id`s in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution:

Declare `mouseOverCheck` in your component. Note that I change how the `data` property is declared to be a function instead:

```
data () {
    return {
        mouseOverCheck: ''
    }
}
```

Then in your HTML, do this:

```
<img 
    v-on:mouseover="mouseOverCheck = video.id" 
    v-on:mouseout="mouseOverCheck = ''" 
    v-bind:src="mouseOverCheck === video.id ? 'images.gif' : 'images.jpg'" />
```

Comment: What if my data needs to be computed? The mouseover/mouseout would not work on the computed data right?

Comment: I mean you can calculate your computed value based on the mouseOverCheck data variable.

Comment: The mouseover event works on my data element, but it does not work on my computed data element. I still cant figure out why.

Comment: If your goal is to assign the computed value a new one based on what happens with the mouseevent (instead of using a data variable) you need to implement the `set` function for your computed variable. Check out https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter